# Setting up intranet with Joomla

Tags: networking, joomla, content-management-system, intranet

I have to set up a company intranet for about 30 users. I'd like a CMS not only for creating content, but to access the files already existent in the local server (such as catalogs and document models). We have a local network and I have access to these folders on my computer, but how do I access them from a local joomla site and extend this access to the other computers in the company without publishing the site online?

Comment: Well it depends on many things - like your network configuration, your computer configuration and etc. First of all: do you have Joomla up and runing in your local machine?

Comment: yeah, I've been using it with the company's website for a while now.

Comment: then try to access it from another computer in your network, by entering your computer's IP address in a browser's address bar.

Answer (score 1):

I know this exact problem... I didn't find a way to access the files through Joomla, but we arranged a collection of important files (quite a lot) on our Joomla Server. There is a component called jifile which is able of indexing all sorts of files. We built up an index with jifile (pretty easy and fast) and now we can search for files and their contents through the Joomla search. If you end up using this approach I'll be happy to help if you have any questions :-)

Comment: I'm gonna talk to my boss about this option, it sounds better than having to access the server. this way we could focus only on important files, although I'd have to copy them to joomla's root. I've tested jifile today indexing a pdf folder but it didn't recognized the files ("empty body").

Comment: "empty body" happens if the pdf contains only an image (check if you can actually selecct the text or if it is an image of the text in your pdf) or if something is wrong with the encoding. If you have image-only pdfs you can index it manually and assign key words / descriptions.